# Formatting datetime

Tags: php, mysql, html

i am trying to format a datetime which comes fromt he database in the format of

```
2012-06-11 21:39:54
```

However i want it to display in the format of `June 11`

How can  do this?

Thanks

Comment: Tried [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) in combination with [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: What have you tried (post the code) and what was the error/problem with that approach?

Comment: Answers using the DateTime class get my vote :)

Comment: possible duplicate of **Related Section**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo date('M d', strtotime('2012-06-11 21:39:54'));
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/tXxxLXMS)

Comment: For June, not Jun: use `F` instead of `M`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use DateTime object.

```
$date = new DateTime($yourString);
$date->format($yourFOrmat);
```

I think that it would be the best way because DateTime is really more powerful than timestamp and date/strtotime functions. 
From the code I gave above you can add functionalities like modifying dates, iterate over the time, compare 2 dates without functions like str_to_time...

```
$date->modify('+1 day');//the day after for example
foreach(new DatePeriod($date,new DateInterval('PT1M'),10){
    $date->format($yourFormat);//iterate each minute
}
```

and so on

Comment: Why are you iterating over the minutes? The OP Just asked for the format conversion. The extra code may be confusing. Also your DateInterval specification is wrong, it should me 'PT1M'.

Comment: Er, yep. It was just because I wanted to show what was the interest of dateTime over the mess with timestamp and date/strtotime functions. If it is too confusing I will erase this part.

Comment: Best just to answer the question that is asked really. If you want yo leave in the extra code, you need to explain clearly what it is doing and why. Unfortunately, as it stands, I can't given you the up vote I want to give for using DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

PHP manual gives an excellent documentation about using Date/Time functions. Basically you will need a  combination of two functions: [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

`strtotime()` will convert your date into Unix timestamp which can be supplied to `date()` as second argument.

The format of date you will need is: `M d`.

**Alternative**: In addition you could also try the MYSQL counterpart which won't require conversion to UNIX timestamp. It is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). Assuming you are using `date` as your Datetime field, you will need something like this,

```
SELECT id,..,DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M %d') as f_date FROM table
```

Answer (score -1):

For formatting date using php, you need to pass timestamp of date
and format specifiers as arguments into date function .
Eg echo date('M d',strtotime('2012-06-11 21:39:54'));

Comment: you don't need that and so far I am concerned I dislike this methodology. There is a more consistant, powerful and readable API with DateTime object.